# C# Why all values of my array are the same?

Tags: c#, arrays

I am sorry for this stupid question, but I haven't understood something big in CSharp (actually many=) ) and I need to find out.
I am new in C#; coming from assembly and C.

Description of what I am trying to do :
I am reading a textfile where data are stored. I am putting these data in a list.

```
public static void ReadFichier()
    {
        TPCANMsg msg = new TPCANMsg();
        msg.DATA = new byte[8];

        string[] cols = new string[8];

        //reading of the file, working perfectly
        string file = "c:\\data\\CanLu.csv";
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        lines=File.ReadAllLines(file).ToList();                                                 //all lines in lines are corrects

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)                                                   //I have tried with a foreach first.
        {
            cols = lines[i].Split(',');                                                         //that's working
            msg.ID = uint.Parse(cols[2],System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);           //that's working
            msg.LEN = byte.Parse(cols[3]);                                                      //that's working

            //it happens that there is not 8 bytes of data. I could have done that with the msg.LEN...
            if (cols[4]!="") msg.DATA[0] = Convert.ToByte(cols[4], 16);                        //that's working 
            if (cols[5] != "") msg.DATA[1] = Convert.ToByte(cols[5], 16);
            if (cols[6] != "") msg.DATA[2] = Convert.ToByte(cols[6], 16);
            if (cols[7] != "") msg.DATA[3] = Convert.ToByte(cols[7], 16);
            if (cols[8] != "") msg.DATA[4] = Convert.ToByte(cols[8], 16);
            if (cols[9] != "") msg.DATA[5] = Convert.ToByte(cols[9], 16);
            if (cols[10] != "") msg.DATA[6] = Convert.ToByte(cols[10], 16);
            if (cols[11] != "") msg.DATA[7] = Convert.ToByte(cols[11], 16);

            Logic.Simul1.Add(msg);                                                             //that's not working
            //in all the lines in Simul1, the simul.data will all get the same value, the last one inserted.
        }

    }
```

the list Simul.1 is declared like that :

```
public static List<TPCANMsg> Simul1 = new List<TPCANMsg>();
```

and the object TPCANMsg is :

```
 public struct TPCANMsg
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 11/29-bit message identifier
    /// </summary>
    public uint ID;
    /// <summary>
    /// Type of the message
    /// </summary>
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public TPCANMessageType MSGTYPE;  
    /// <summary>
    /// Data Length Code of the message (0..8)
    /// </summary>
    public byte LEN;      
    /// <summary>
    /// Data of the message (DATA[0]..DATA[7])
    /// </summary>
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
    public byte[] DATA;   
}
```

I can't change anything there, it is coming from the driver of the USBReader that I am using.

So in my list Simul1, all simul.ID are good, all simul.LEN are good, BUT all simul1.DATA are the same egual as the last one inserted.
Why all simul1.data are pointing to the same address ? why not the others? I don't get it.
This variable, pointer, address was more clear in c.

thanks

Comment: The problem is that you are adding the same msg again and again. If you later change any data in msg.DATA you will see this change in every array element because they all share the same byte[] instance.

Answer (score 1):

Create a *new* `msg` each loop. As it is now, empty columns won't overwrite previous values, because the values are only set when `col[..] != ""`. Alternatively, always set the value *regardless* of if the column has a value.

```
// move this
// TPCANMsg msg = new TPCANMsg();
// msg.DATA = new byte[8];

..

for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)                                                  
{
    // Down here, so a NEW object is always created and used.
    // This also includes a NEW data array, which has all-0's for default values.
    TPCANMsg msg = new TPCANMsg();
    msg.DATA = new byte[8];

    ..
```

Another approach, to re-use the same object, would be to keep it as in the original and then ensure that *every* DATA slot is assigned a value each loop, or to the default value as necessary. This code uses the [conditional / ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) to do such.

```
// Ensure to assign a value to EACH data slot on EACH loop.
// This value might be 0 (overwriting the value in the last loop).
msg.DATA[0] = cols[4]!=""
    ? Convert.ToByte(cols[4], 16)  // have a column value? assign it.
    : 0;                           // nope: assign 0 to replace previous loop's value!
 
..
```

Or with a more traditional if-else:

```
if (cols[4]!="")
    msg.DATA[0] = Convert.ToByte(cols[4], 16);
} else {
    msg.DATA[0] = 0; // reset previous loop's value if column empty!
}
 
..
```

Comment: You second approach will only work if you create at least assign a new `byte[]` to `msg.DaATA` on each iteration.